# How to populate identity applicationuser data in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying add a model with respect to users (ApplicationUser) and for that i created a model my problem is the data is not displaying in view (username for particular post)

**Model**

```
public class OrganizationViewModel
{
    public ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create(OrganizationViewModel organizationviewmodel)
        {
            var getuserid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var userid = db.Users.Single(s => s.Id == getuserid);
            var organizationvmodel = new Organization
            {
                AppUser = userid,
                Name = organizationviewmodel.Name
            };
            db.Organizations.Add(organizationvmodel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

But in view which means index.cshtml when i try to populate it as a list its empty just like this [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmAvJ.png)

**View**

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppUser.UserName)
                @ViewBag.UserName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.OrganizationId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.OrganizationId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.OrganizationId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Please give me a good solution because i am very new to asp.net mvc

Comment: What are you doing on the index page's controller?

Comment: return View(db.Organizations.ToList());